# ImageMagick +distort Perspective

Tags: imagemagick

Anyone know how I can get this name plate positioned in roughly this place using +distort Perspective? Ive tried everything. the background image is 1800x1800 (doesn't look like its uploading the first image)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't use ImageMagick for this TBH.  If you are just processing one image,  then use Photoshop or GIMP. A simple manual distort is all that is required.

Comment: Im doing 1000's of images

Comment: but are they all exactly in the same position?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid no automate places your signboard right. One reason is that the perspective of the image is not perfectly drawn, thus it's not extractable by any AI application.

Place it manually, use the pattern of the metal as your reference.

[image]

I rotated it approximately right and moved the corners of the board with the distort tool in Photoshop to follow the lines of the metal pattern. At least no new contradictions were inserted.

Comment: Ive actually done it before very successfully I just can't remember how https://i.seadn.io/gcs/files/c8c1fcda4cb8938841eaaa959ad34f10.png?auto=format&w=828